# PowerPoint VBA Recognizing Shapes in a Grouping

Tags: vba, powerpoint, powerpoint-2013

I am trying to create a simple PowerPoint file to capture a series of milestones for a project portfolio. I have created the following Macro to create the milestone visual and group the shapes. However, I am looking to create another macro for updating/statusing the milestone. Specifically, I want the user to select the group and then run a macro to that will allow the user to update the date and move the shapes accordingly or, if the task is complete, fill in the shape.

I struggle with the initiation of the update macro to identify the shapes and its' content to complete the calculation. For example, I don't know how to read in the date in to move the milestone left/right based on the new date. Any help is appreciated!

Code:

```
Private Sub EnterTask_Click()

Dim Sld As Slide
Dim shapeMile As Shape
Dim shapeTask As Shape
Dim shapeECD As Shape
Dim dateECD As String
Dim taskText As String

Dim StatusBox As Shape

dateECD = "6/12/18"
taskText = "Task #1"

Set Sld = Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide

With Sld

'Create shape with Specified Dimensions and Slide Position
Set shapeMile = Sld.Shapes.AddShape(Type:=msoShapeIsoscelesTriangle, _
    Left:=25, Top:=150, Width:=15, Height:=15)

    With shapeMile
        .Rotation = 180
        .Tags.Add "Milestone", "Bug"
        .Line.Visible = msoTrue
        .Fill.Visible = msoFalse
        .Shadow.Visible = msoFalse

    End With

Set shapeECD = Sld.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
    Left:=8, Top:=165, Width:=50, Height:=30)

    With shapeECD
        .Tags.Add "Milestone", "ECD"
        .Line.Visible = msoFalse
        .Fill.Visible = msoFalse
        .Shadow.Visible = msoFalse
        .TextFrame.TextRange.Characters.Text = dateECD
        .TextFrame.TextRange.Paragraphs.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = ppAlignCenter
        .TextFrame.VerticalAnchor = msoAnchorTop
        .TextFrame.HorizontalAnchor = msoAnchorCenter
        .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 8
        .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Name = "Arial"
        .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Italic = msoFalse
        .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    End With

Set shapeTask = Sld.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
    Left:=8, Top:=135, Width:=50, Height:=30)

    With shapeTask
        .Tags.Add "Milestone", "Task"
        .Line.Visible = msoFalse
        .Fill.Visible = msoFalse
        .Shadow.Visible = msoFalse
        .TextFrame.TextRange.Characters.Text = taskText
        .TextFrame.TextRange.Paragraphs.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = ppAlignCenter
        .TextFrame.VerticalAnchor = msoAnchorTop
        .TextFrame.HorizontalAnchor = msoAnchorCenter
        .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 8
        .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Name = "Arial"
        .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Italic = msoFalse
        .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    End With

.Shapes.Range(Array(shapeMile.Name, shapeECD.Name, shapeTask.Name)).Group

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: So what exactly is your problem? This macro above works fine.

Comment: Correct. The above macro works fine. I want to create a second macro where I can manipulate the group created by the above macro. For example, if the user wants to revise the dateECD from "6/12/18" to "8/10/18" via a MessageBox input. How can I, with the selection of the initial group, determine which shape is shapeECD and that its' text is?

Comment: The member here will not do the programming work for you, they will give you ghelp when you stuck in certain specific problems. The best starting point how make something is to google and to use the microsoft object model. When you press F1 in the VBA Window (Alt+F11) you get directly to the object model. when you look for shapes you easily get ideas how to scan through all shapes and find one with specific text, type,...

Comment: Thanks Christine. Not looking for someone to do the programming, just looking for the starting points and if it is possible.

Comment: Since you are adding tags to each of the shapes. You could enumerate through the group items of the selected group to retrieve the tag value on it. If it matches “ECD” then you have the desired shape, you can then update the text on it.